# IZPack copy external files to installpath

Tags: java, ant, jar, installation, izpack

i have a izpack installer and inside of it my project with a media folder(500 MB). When i start the installer, i must wait a few seconds because it unpacks all files.

My question is: Can i select files(the media folder) outside the package to copy it, to the installpath?

With google i found only the solution on bottom of this page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/izpack-user/mjA6AXzSouw

Answer (score 1):

you can run an ANT target to copy this media file (presumably extracted from the same **.zip** file which contains `installer.jar`, although this is up to you).

- `install.xml:`

  `<listeners>
     <listener classname="AntActionInstallerListener" stage="install" />
     <listener classname="AntActionUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall" />
  </listeners>`
- `UserInputSpec.xml:`

  `<field type="file" align="left" variable=`**`"the.file"`**`>
     <spec txt="" size="25" set=""/>
  </field>`
- `UserInputPanel:` ask user to locate and select the media file, through the `File Chooser` field. The file location will be saved in `the.file` variable, as shown above.
- `AntActionsSpec.xml:`

  `<antcall buildfile=`**`"location of ANT_XML_FILE"`**`order="afterpacks">
     <target name=`**`"copyFile"`**`></target>
     <property name=`**`"dest.dir"`**`value=`**`"$INSTALL_PATH"`**`></property>
     <property name=`**`"the_file"`**`value=`**`"${the.file}"`**`></property>
  </antcall>`
- `ANT_XML_FILE:`
  `<target name=`**`"copyFile"`**`>
     <copy todir=`**`"${dest.dir}"`**`file=`**`"${the_file}"`**`/>
  </target>`